# How can I update my Flink version programmatically

Tags: apache-flink

At the moment I have Flink 0.8.1 installed on my machine. I installed it via Maven and would like to know how I can update it. Do I have to deinstall everything in order to update to the current version? Or can I do it via Maven?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "installed it via Maven". If you have a Eclipse or Intellij project, just update the version number of your specified Flink dependencies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a Maven project which depends on Apache Flink you can simply update the version of the Flink dependencies in your project's `pom.xml` file. Just run `mvn clean compile` again and Maven will fetch all required dependencies.

The old dependencies will remain in your local Maven repository (`~/.m2/repository/`). You can "uninstall" the old Flink dependencies by deleting the corresponding jar files.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I managed to update my project's pom.xml. But where are the files saved? When I want to start Flink via terminal I need to navigate there first, but at the moment I only have my old 0.8.1 folder.

Comment: Maven stores all downloaded and installed jar files in a local repository. For Linux and OSX, the repository is in `~/.m2/repository` for Windows, the repository is usually `C:\Documents and Settings\user-name\.m2`. However, Maven is a tool to build software, not a tool to install software. If you want to start a local Flink instance, I would recommend to follow the [setup instructions](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-0.9/setup/local_setup.html).